# Display multiple user controls in one asp:placeholder with randomizing

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a webform with three user controls loaded in three asp:placeholders containing questions that needs to be randomized from a set of total 20 questions(so, 20 user controls):

```
const string randomQuestion1 = "~/Qset1";
const string randomQuestion2 = "~/Qset2";
const string randomQuestion3 = "~/Qset3";
const string randomQuestion4 = "~/Qset4";
const string randomQuestion5 = "~/Qset5";


void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    string questionPath1 = GetRandomQuestionPath1();
    string questionPath2 = GetRandomQuestionPath2();
    string questionPath3 = GetRandomQuestionPath3();

    Control question1 = Page.LoadControl(questionPath1);
    Control question2 = Page.LoadControl(questionPath2);
    Control question3 = Page.LoadControl(questionPath3);

    PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(question1);
    PlaceHolder2.Controls.Add(question2);
    PlaceHolder3.Controls.Add(question3);
}


protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // add data to database...       
}

}

private string GetRandomQuestionPath1() 
{
    Random rnd = new Random(); 
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(MapPath(randomQuestion1), "*.ascx");
    string questionPath = Path.GetFileName(files[rnd.Next(files.Length)]); 

    return Path.Combine(randomQuestion1, questionPath);
} 

private string GetRandomQuestionPath2() 
{
    Random rnd = new Random(); 
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(MapPath(randomQuestion2), "*.ascx");
    string questionPath = Path.GetFileName(files[rnd.Next(files.Length)]); 

    return Path.Combine(randomQuestion2, questionPath);
}

private string GetRandomQuestionPath3() 
{
    Random rnd = new Random(); 
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(MapPath(randomQuestion3), "*.ascx");
    string questionPath = Path.GetFileName(files[rnd.Next(files.Length)]); 

    return Path.Combine(randomQuestion3, questionPath);
}
```

How can i place three user controls in one asp:placeholder and randomize these user controls from one directory instead of several?

Thank you :)

Edit:

Also, i want to get the property's of the three randomized usercontrols. These usercontrols contain only one textbox.
I can get the property if the usercontrol is added staticly. It failes when added dynamicly. Using <%@ Reference Control="~/Qset1/qOne.ascx" %> in the aspx file.

Comment: Anyone? Or is the construction kinda weird?

Comment: Maybe a better approach would be to add randomized data?